# iOS could not be installed at this time

Tags: ios, trigger.io

So I have tried everything and am currently beating my head against the desk. I am using trigger.io to generate apps for both android and ios. The android apps work just find and I am able to distribute with MDM as needed. The ios app on the other hand just keeps throwing the error " could not be installed at this time."

I have generated and regenerated my certificates/profiles using the documentation provided and still nothing. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks!
Bill

Comment: I just received a down vote for my question. I assure you I have spent over 8 hours of research trying to get this working. I have tried generating both development and distribution certificates, I have added my ios devices UUID to the provisioning profile, and always the same message without change. Further more I have gone through every line of text from the trigger.io ios documentation with a fine tooth comb. If you believe I have missed something, PLEASE enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of additional things you can check:

- Is Xcode up to date? Use the App Store to check for updates and install any updates if required.
- Do you have the relevant iOS SDK installed in Xcode? Open up Xcode, go to Preferences and check the "Downloads" tab. Install any missing components that are required by your application (e.g. the supported iOS version needed for your app).
- Does your iOS device support the minimum iOS version required by your application? Make sure you are running the minimum supported iOS. A difference in the installed version and the build version could be preventing install.
- Does "Development Mode" need to be enabled on your device? Use Xcode > Window > Devices to see if Development Mode needs to be installed on your device. This will install some debugging tools to your device but won't affect any existing apps.
- Check that your device is trusted with the computer you are using. Disconnect the USB cable and reconnect. You may be prompted on both the device and computer to "trust" each other.
- Unlock your device with passcode and try running the app again to see if that makes a difference.

Hopefully one of these is your issue. Please comment if any of these helped.